# Как использовать правильно DI-контейнер

Tags: php

У меня следующая задача:

В проекте планирую использовать логгер (перед созданием объекта логгера, требуется его конфигурировать) у этого логгера могут быть разные зависимост и т.д.

Решил использовать DI-контейнер, ранее с ними не работал. (например простой DI контейнер `Pimple`)

Правильно понимаю, что если я создаю сам контейнер в каком-то своем файле, далее при использовании этого контейнера в других файлах, мне придется заново описывать все связи и сервисы в этом контейнере? 
Или есть какие-то режимы работы (типа синглтона)?

Comment: Т.е. каким образом могу задать зависимости для своего логгера и сконфигурировать его, а далее во всем проекте вытаскивать готовый объект из контейнера?

Comment: DI-контейнер, по сути, следует использовать только если объекты создаются на лету, например, роутер, который создает экземпляр конкретного контролллера. В этот экземпляр, в соответствии со специйфикацией, добавляются все зависимости

Answer (score 2):

DI - это внедрение зависимостей. Ваша зависимость - это логгер. Как ее внедрить - есть несколько способов, я обычно использую внедрение через конструктор.

Представьте, что у вас нет никакого DI контейнера.
Например, у вас есть какой-нибудь класс, который использует какой-нибудь логгер LoggerInterface.

Вы его спокойно описываете

```
class Handler
{
  private $logger;

  public function __container(LoggerInterface $logger)
  {
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }

  public function save($data)
  {
    // saving...
    $this->logger->logMessage('message');
    // other handling...
  }
}
```

В этом коде нет никакого упоминания о DI контейнере.

Теперь вам необходимо отдельно описать логику внедрения. Она может отличаться от конкретных DI контейнеров. Но суть в том, что она идет отдельно от вашего приложения, например можно сделать файлик di-config.php, описать в нем конфиг DI и подключать его где надо.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Получается, если мне в десятках классов (каждый класс в отдельном файле) нужно использовать логирование, то в каждый файл подключить файл с конфигов DI контейнера?

Comment: Нет, желательно в классах и их файлах не упоминать ничего о DI. Подключаете его где-нибудь в самом начале перед запуском приложения. DI контейнеры обычно сами распознают классы в конструкторах и внедряют зависимости согласно конфигу.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

А как можно быть уверенным в том, что если какой-то сервис имеет зависимость, то эта зависимость имеется в контейнере и правильно будет инициализирована без ошибок ?


Т.е. вот такой код `$object = $container["my_service"];` может вызвать ошибки, если зависимости потерялись, или при инициализации возникли ошибки. 

А я по умолчанию работаю с `$object` как с объектом.. это тоже вызовет кучу ошибок, т.к. сервис не создался.

Comment: Получается нужно всегда проверять созданный сервис, типа того:

`$object = $container["my_service"]; if($object instanceof myServiceClass) { .. }` ?

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf, ну это общий вопрос обработки ошибок. Если нужна спец. обработка ситуаций, когда сервис не создался - да, надо делать либо проверки либо try/catch. Либо, может быть, в документации конкретного di есть примеры с кодом.